# How to implement concurrent calls in C# console app, .NET 4.5?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, parallel-processing

I'm polling an external queue for job requests, then process the job (which takes ~1 minute). Currently, I'm doing it synchronously, which is inefficient because if there were 10 jobs, it would take 10 minutes. The machine can handle up to 5 jobs at the same time, so it should be able to process 10 jobs in ~2 minutes.

I've never done multi-threading, I've tried to read about async, await, Task.Run, but haven't had any success implementing it. Any suggestions on a simple way to implement this pseudocode?

```
while(concurrentJobs <= 5)
{
    job = pollForJob(); // synchronous

    processJob(job); // want to do this in background so that I can poll for next job
}

void processJob(job)
{
    concurrentJobs++;
    doStuff(); // takes 1 minute
    concurrentJobs--;
}
```

Comment: "haven't had any success implementing it." What problems are you facing, questions like yours is too broad to cover in a single answer. Please let us know the specific issues you are having with multithreading.

Comment: Use a `BlockingCollection` for your queue.  You can then have 5 different threads all asking it for an item at the same time, and it will all just work out.  You can then have one or more separate threads producing content that is added to the collection.

Comment: Could you have a look at my question here? stackoverflow.com/questions/55039226/polling-in-the-cloud. +1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you have a producer-consumer model. In this case `Parallel` class won't do you any good, because a new job can come any time. You can only use `Parallel` class when you know beforehand what you need to do.

If, however, a new job can come any time I would use the following approach.

#### Producer

Write a separate long-running `Task` or use `Thread`. This thread receives jobs from network (such as from a queue or a database) or whatever and puts items into the shared memory.

#### Shared memory

Use `BlockingCollection` to add and take jobs. This acts as a mediator between producer and consumer.

#### Consumer

Exactly the same as producer - a separate `Thread` that checks the shared memory for any available item. Once an item is retrieved from a queue you can process it at will.

---

Now if you have such separation, you can easily spawn several producers and consumers, each running in its own thread.

Comment: Could you have a look at my question here? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55039226/polling-in-the-cloud.  Is it better to use a .NET Service or a .NET Console app if I am planning to migrate an internally hosted server to the cloud in future? +1.

Answer (score 0):

Have you ever tried the parallel for each? It's simple.

Here a MSDN [example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460720.aspx)

```
Parallel.ForEach(concurrentJobs , currentJob =>
{
    processJob(currentJob);
});
```

Comment: `Parallel.ForEach` doesn't take an integer as it's first parameter.  He'd need to create a generator for his item creation before he could do this.

Answer (score 0):

Similar to [Romulo's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18644289/80274), but a little more fleshed out.

First you need to turn your `pollForJob()` function to an `IEnumerable`

```
private IEnumerable<Job> JobEnumerator()
{
   Job job;
   while((job = pollForJob()) != null)
   {
       yield return job;
   }
}
```

Then you can use it with the [Parallel.ForEach](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.parallel.foreach.aspx) class

```
Parallel.ForEach(JobEnumerator(), 
         new ParallelOptions() {MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 5}, 
         processJob);
```

This will block on the line `Parallel.ForEach` but it will run 5 instances of the `processJob(Job job)` function at the same time.