# Polling in the cloud

Tags: c#, rabbitmq, polling

I am creating an app, which will poll a rabbitmq queue for messages.  I have three choices:

1. Console app, which listens for new messages
2. Windows service, which listens for new messages
3. Web API, which listens for new messages

In normal circumstances I would choose a windows service because it is a long running process and a TCP connection is available to the RabbitMQ server.  However, how would this work if we decided to move the application to the cloud in future? The way that I understand it is that I can create a web job for a console app, however this is not possible for a windows service.

Q1) As I am thinking about the cloud, then should I be using a web api for this?

Q2) Is a console app more suitable than a windows service in the cloud?

I am specifically asking if the options I have chosen are available in the cloud.

Comment: Depends on the *cloud*. All cloud vendors have a scheduling service but the specifics differ between them. A common action is to call an HTTP service that implements the scheduled job's actual code, or call a Lambda/Function/Whatever serverless. I suspect all of them already have recurring triggers for their serverless offerings too

Comment: @Panagiotis Kanavos, thanks .  Would you say a web api is more suitable for this in the cloud?

Comment: No. There are a lot of options, each suitable for a different thing. Maybe you just want to trigger a Lambda? Or call an API? Or post a message to a queue? Depends on what you actually want to do. RPC-style calls have no retries after all, while queued messages can be delayed. With a lambda and a recurring trigger you get rid of both the scheduler and the need to somehow host the job

Comment: @Panagiotis Kanavos, if you could summarise the options in an answer for AWS or Azure then that would help.  I am trying to learn more about the scatter gatherer pattern and the cloud.